# Java Error: "Your security settings have blocked a local application from running"

Tags: java, security, applet

I'm trying to run this simple HelloWorld code written in Java from my browser ([Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)):

```
public class HelloWorld extends JApplet {
public void init() {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello World");
                add(lbl);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
```

I compiled it with [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), and then I created a WebApplication project. The [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) code that runs the applet is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><applet code="HelloWorld" archive="applet_HelloWorld.jar"  width="590" height="530"></applet></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If run the applet from NetBeans it works. But when I run the HTML code by double clicking it, the following message pops up from the browser:

> Your security settings have blocked a local application from running.

I tried with Internet Explorer and Firefox but nothing.

This message started to appear after the last update of Java. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 59):

After reading [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements in Detail](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html)  mention..

> With the introduced changes it is most likely that no end-user is able to run your application when they are either self-signed or unsigned.

..I was wondering how this would go for loose class files - the 'simplest' applets of all.

### Local file system

> [image: Dialog: Your security settings have blocked a local application from running]
>
> Your security settings have blocked a local application from running

That is the dialog seen for an applet consisting of loose class files being loaded off the **local file system** when the JRE is set to the default 'High' security setting.

---

Note that a slight quirk of the JRE only produced that on point 3 of.

1. Load the applet page to see a broken applet symbol that leads to an empty console.

   Open the Java settings and set the level to **Medium**.

   Close browser & Java settings.
2. Load the applet page to see the applet.

   Open the Java settings and set the level to **High**.

   Close browser & Java settings.
3. Load the applet page to see a broken applet symbol ***& the above dialog.***

### Internet

If you load the simple applet (loose class file) seen at this [resizable applet demo](http://pscode.org/test/resize/) off the **internet** - which boasts an `applet` element of:

```html
<applet
    code="PlafChanger.class"
    codebase="."
    alt="Pluggable Look'n'Feel Changer appears here if Java is enabled"
    width='100%'
    height='250'>
<p>Pluggable Look'n'Feel Changer appears here in a Java capable browser.</p>
</applet>
```

It also seems to load successfully.  Implying that:-

***Applets loaded from the local file system are now subject to a stricter security sandbox than those loaded from the internet or a local server.***

### Security settings descriptions

As of Java 7 update 51.

- **Very High**: *Most secure setting - Only Java applications identified by a non-expired certificate from a trusted authority will be allowed to run.*
- **High (minimum recommended)**: *Java applications identified by a certificate from a trusted authority will be allowed to run.*
- **Medium** - *All Java applications will be allowed to run after presenting a security prompt.*

Comment: Thanks! I was also compiling with SDK6 (I don't know why) actually.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Is there a way to modify loose class files to make them trusted if they're on a site that's actually trusted?

Comment: @ChristopherBruce  No.

Comment: some windows 8 users can't search for "java control panel" so they should access it directly through  C:\program files\java\jre7\bin\javacpl.exe

Comment: Note that Oracle have now removed the Medium Java security setting. Quoting from https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml: "Starting with Java 8 Update 20, the Medium security level has been removed from the Java Control Panel. Only High and Very High levels are available."

Comment: @user2023370  Yes, it was always heading that way.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 21):

I faced the same issue today, and I was able to fix the issue by changing the security settings on the Java Control Panel from `HIGH` to `MEDIUM`.

Well, setting the Java Security Setting to MEDIUM permanently is not really recommended as this will allow potentialy malicious software to run on your system and not be blocked. So I suggest after running your applet you may want to change back the setting to HIGH.

[Location of the Java Control Panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml#control%20panel)

[Change the setting of the Control Panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)

Comment: Or instead "Add an Exception" if you trust the source. I prefer this over rockstar's suggestion, because usually (I think) we forget change back setting of a software!

Comment: Per java.com: "Starting with Java 8 Update 20, the Medium security level has been removed from the Java Control Panel. Only High and Very High levels are available."

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Double click on *Java*
3. Open the *Security* tab
4. Select *Medium*
5. Click on *Apply*
6. Restart your web browser

That's it!

[image]

Comment: I didn't find "Medium" under the Security tab. Which operation system and what version of Java are you using?

Comment: I agree with Peter's statement. I could not find Medium in Security tab.

Comment: Under security tab, there is a header named "security level". it has 3 levels : very high, high and medium.

Comment: Starting with java 8 there is no more Medium

Answer (score 12):

If you are using [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), these settings are available using `/usr/bin/jcontrol` (or your path setting to get the current Java tools). You can also edit the files in `~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties` to set "deployment.security.level=MEDIUM".

Surprisingly, this information is not readily available from the Oracle web site. I miss java.sun.com...

Answer (score 8):

If you have no Medium security level, then you should add your application to the **Exception Site List** (*Java Control Panel* → *Security* tab).

1. Open your applet in a browser and copy the contents of your address bar.
   [image: screenshot of applet's address in the address bar]
2. Go to *Control Panel* → *Java Control Panel* → *Security* tab and press the <kbd>Edit Site List...</kbd> button.
   [image: screenshot of Java Control Panel's Security tab]
3. Press the <kbd>Add</kbd> button, insert your path and press Enter.
   [image: screenshot of Exception Site List]
4. Press <kbd>Continue</kbd> on the security warning that appears. 
   [image: screenshot of Security Warning - FILE Location alert prompt]
5. Open the applet again and don't forget to press <kbd>Run</kbd> on the pop-up window.
   [image: screenshot of Security Warning]

Answer (score 3):

If you are like me whose Java Control Panel **does not show Security slider** under Security Tab to change security level from High to Medium then follow these instructions: [Java known bug: security slider not visible](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_securityslider.xml).

---

#### Symptoms:

> After installation, the checkbox to enable/disable Java and the security level slider do not appear in the Java Control Panel Security tab. This can occur with 7u10 and above.

#### Cause

> This is due to a conflict that Java 7u10 and above have with standalone installations of JavaFX. 
>   Example: If Java 7u5 and JavaFX 2.1.1 are installed and if Java is updated to 7u11, the Java Control Panel does not show the checkbox or security slider.

#### Resolution

> It is recommended to uninstall all versions of Java and JavaFX before installing Java 7u10 and above.
>   Please follow the steps below for resolving this issue.
>    1. Remove all versions of Java and JavaFX through the Windows Uninstall Control Panel. Instructions on [uninstalling Java](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml).
>    2. Run the Microsoft uninstall utility to repair corrupted registry keys that prevents programs from being completely uninstalled or blocking new installations and updates.
>    3. Download and install the Windows [offline installer](http://www.java.com/en/download/windows_offline.jsp) package.

Answer (score 1):

My problem case was to run portecle.jnlp file locally using Java8.

What worked for me was

1. Start Programs --> Java --> Configure Java...
2. Go to Security --> Edit Site List...
3. Add http://portecle.sourceforce.net
4. Start *javaws portecle.jnlp* in CMD prompt

On step 3, you might try also to add file:///c:/path/portecle.jnlp, but this addition didn't help with my case.

Comment: What about from a location on your PC?  I have Windows 10 (not sure if that matters) with version 8. The UI is kind of buggy, and doesn't let me add a directory.

Comment: Okay, figured it out. Have to use, "file:///"  I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am using an older Data Structure and Algs book that comes with Java Applets for practice. So I needed to store and run some applets locally. I am currently running Windows 10 OS with Edge, Chrome, and IE 11.

Running applets seem to only be allowed in IE11, and as other have mentioned you have to add the applet to the exception list. My issue was since I am storing these locally, and opening them in IE, it opened with path starting with "C:\..."  Adding the full path using, "file///..." like mentioned in one of the other answers didn't work for me.

The fix:
So, I just added(without the quotes), "file:///" to the exception site list and finally got it working. This also allows me to run any applet stored locally, and I do not have to explicitly add an exception for each applet path.

I plan to remove the exception from the list once I am done using the programs, and only add it back as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Java applets do create a security risk, hence are disabled in most modern browsers. You have to lower the security to run it. There is a [guide by Oracle](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) for that.

Comment: I tried to put the security level to its minimum value but it didn't work. The problem arose after the last Java update. Before everything was working properly.

Comment: Resolved: the problem was that the compiler used JDK6 instead of JDK7.

Comment: Note to future me-like people reading this: If (in the command line where you `javac`-compiled the class file in the first place) the `java -version` command tells you that you're *already* running the latest version, then you may need to completely uninstall everything "Java" from the `appwiz.cpl` list, then restart your computer and reinstall the latest JDK from a fresh download, *then* go into the Java Control Panel and slide the security down to "medium".

Answer (score 0):

- Starting with Java 8, there is no "medium" risk setting in the Security tab under Java
- You will keep getting this error till you revert to older Java (suggested Java 7, it has hit the end of life though).
- Install both 32-bit and 64-bit version because browsers are still 32-bit, even on a 64-bit machine, 64-bit OS