# Load a JFrame into a html

Tags: java, html, swing, jframe

I am trying to open my Applet.jar in a html code.

My Java code is :

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setTitle("Example");
        //more lines code base in JFrame with button,labels etc
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My html code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Java Applet Example</h1>

<p><object type="application/x-java-applet" width="300" height="300"> <param name="code" value="NewJFrame.class" /> <param name="archive" value="20130717_Applet.jar" /> <param name="mayscript" value="true" /> Java failed to load </object></p>

</body>
</html>
```

So when i am trying to open the html file with a browser it throws me up :

Java Error: “ClassNotFoundException NewJFrame.class”

I change the security for the java control panel to Medium from High but i get the same error.

Comment: Try changing to low. Not an expert here but I guess archives need to be digitally signed. I may be wrong :)

Comment: There is no "Low" option the minimum is Medium

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196425/java-error-your-security-settings-have-blocked-a-local-application-from-runnin

Comment: I had see this post, this is the reason that i change the security from High to Medium.,.. but it doesn't work! So i create a new post with my code to see if someone could help me!

Comment: `<applet>` tags are obsolete try using `<object>` tags.

Comment: Now i replace in my html code the applet with : <p><object type="application/x-java-applet" width="300" height="300">
    <param name="code" value="NewJFrame.class" />
    <param name="archive" value="20130717_Applet.jar" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
    Java failed to load
</object></p>
And it throw me up the error that "ClassNotFoundException NewJFrame.class "

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK a class needs to extend one of the applet classes to run the class as an applet.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JApplet {
```

Since applets do not provided a `setTitle` method (at least not directly), comment out the line

```
setTitle("Example");
```

---

To run the application directly using a `JFrame`, [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) could be used

Comment: When i tried it, it put me an error on java for the setTitle method!

Comment: As you would expect as applets don't have a frame title. Comment that line out

Comment: My code it's not only this line inside the initComponets. But i write only this line here to be more easily to understand it!