# Java applet won't load JAR from local machine on any browser

Tags: java, applet

I have looked on the web and found similar questions on SO but none are helping me. I need to test an HTML page containing an applet on my local machine and it just won't work.

My HTML looks like this:

```
applet.innerHTML = ' \
    <applet id="applet" code="pulpcore.platform.applet.CoreApplet" codebase="." width="800" height="600"> \
        <param name="archive" value="test.jar"> \
        <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false"> \
        <param name="cache_option" value="Plugin"> \
        \
        <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"> \
        <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xms150M -Xmx700M -Djnlp.packEnabled=false -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false"> \
        \
    </applet>';
```

The JAR file is in the same dir as the HTML file so I think `codebase="."` is right... I tried `codebase="file:///."` with no luck either.

I *thought* I had it working in Chrome (on Windows 7) but then I get this message:

[image]

On IE10 and FF it just fails immediately. Applets/web-dev aren't my specialities, I'm a java guy just testing the functionality of the applet before deploying. The applet is built into a local dir by an Ant script so I don't really want to go copying it to another dir so it can be hosted locally. I have to go that route I think IIS7 is already running on my PC so that's my preference... but this definitely used to work.

Oh - and I *am* running the latest version of Chrome (updated today).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196425/java-error-your-security-settings-have-blocked-a-local-application-from-runnin seems to be the same issue, but can someone confirm who knows better? Why is my newest version of Chrome not running the latest Java - isn't Java built in to Chrome these days?

Comment: As far as I know, Java is still standalone so it's probably worth checking your local install version of Java...