# "Security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running" as developer

Tags: java, security, applet, processing

I have a java applet on a website (http://martinogames.x10.mx/) but it gets blocked by java security settings.  It is a signed applet created using the AppletMaker tool in processing.  I know how to allow access on my computer (java security settings to medium/whitelist the site), but I want to know how to get Java to accept it for other users.  I am the developer and should have access to all information needed to do this, if it is possible.

Thanks in advance,
-Peperononew

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157450/how-to-make-a-machine-trust-a-self-signed-java-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to buy a real certificate and sign it with that. Otherwise it would require users to trust your certificate, which is not secure at all (you're not a trustworthy entity).