# Java 7 Update 45 (64-bit) blocking java applet self signed

Tags: java, applet, self-signed

I'm seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157450/how-to-make-a-machine-trust-a-self-signed-java-application), and I want know if this solution will work only on Java settings in my computer or this will work in all computers with Java installed? Because I want that my applet (.jar) works in all computers with Java installed, and with security settings default (High) that already comes when Java installed [see](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml).

Someone could give me a tip?

Thank in advance!

Comment: The short answer is no, since that would defeat the point. Java disabled running unsigned/self-signed applets by default because it was a massive security hole. If you have access to every client it will run on, you can add your applet to the whitelist, but otherwise no, you can't defeat that check from the host-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the  **answer** given into the post you have mentioned  which is

Just Go To **Startmenu >>Java >>Configure Java >> Security >> Edit site list >> copy and paste your Link with problem >>** OK Problem fixed :)

This you have to do in each and every computer in which you want to run your applets , untill you are using self signed applets.

Alternative Solution : Just Use **Signed Applets**

---

**Update**

To understand the diffrence between **Unsigned , Self-Signed and Signed Applets** i suggest you to read this [Java Applets: Unsigned vs Self-Signed vs Signed](http://www.mendoweb.be/blog/java-applets-unsigned-vs-self-signed-vs-signed/)

In the java Update **java7u51** Adding sites in exception list has been changed slightly , you may also look this post for that 
[Upcoming Exception Site List in 7u51](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in)

Comment: I have tried this on a site with a popup applet, and it doesn't work.  Alternate solution?

Comment: Is your applet self signed ?

Comment: Yes, I understand the differences.  The game is self-signed, but for some reason, it says that Java doesn't allowed applets without an approved certificate.

Comment: @Neeraj Jain, please, could give me some examples of sites where buy a good certificate for a good price?

Comment: @Coringa Here is the list [List of supported SSL certificate types and vendors for](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11413/~/list-of-supported-ssl-certificate-types-and-vendors-for-filemaker-platform)

Comment: @Neeraj Jain, which these you recommend?

Comment: Verisign it is the most trusted certificate .

Comment: Since I haven't got a solution to my problem here, I've posted something on Arqade. Check it out here http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215977/games-from-gamejolt-com-arent-permitted-to-run