# Application blocked on Coldfusion 9 install on windows 2008 R2

Tags: java, coldfusion, installation

I installed CF9 on win2008 R2.  For the most part it runs.  However, if for example, you go to the mappings section and click on the Browse button you get this error: "Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running.  Also Cfajaxyproxy will not work.  I'm assuming that's because the jre is being blocked.  I can't seem to find any security settings that would cause this to happen.  Any help is appreciated.

THX

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it in ages, but IIRC the CF Administrator does use a java applet for the browse feature on the Mappings screen. This error message is part of increased security settings for java applications.

As an aside, when you get an unknown error, always do a search on the error message first. That phrase turns up a bunch of links describing how to modify your security settings, and more importantly - the implications of changing those settings:

- [Security level settings in the Java Control Panel](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)
- [What should I do when I see a security prompt from Java?](http://java.com/en/download/help/appsecuritydialogs.xml)
- [Java Error: “Your security settings have blocked a local application from running”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196425/java-error-your-security-settings-have-blocked-a-local-application-from-runnin)

Having said that, I believe the applet is optional. You should still be able to type paths into the text boxes and submit the changes - without using the applet.

As far as `cfajaxyproxy` that sounds like that may be different issue. You should open a separate question. Be sure to include a [small repro case](http://www.sscce.org/), a description of how it "will not work" and any javascript error messages.