# How to run a Java applet that is not signed

Tags: java, security, applet, java-web-start

I know to run a java applet that is not signed by whitelisting it in java security option, but I need to run a java applet through html that is stored in my computer and I cannot add the path of that html file to the java security whitelist since only http and other web policies' URL can be added to the whitelist not path from  my own computer.

How to solve this problem? Do I need to create a certificate for the file? If yes how? or are there any other solutions?

Comment: Since it will be necessary to digitally sign the applet prior to deploying it, you might as well sign it now.  A few changes to the build script and the code will automatically be jarred and signed.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can add your local your local file to exception list this way:

file:///C:/applet/myapplet.jar

If above didn't work you can try the following. You used to be able to run local applets by changing Java security to Medium. However Oracle removed the Medium security option starting from Java 8 update 20.

2) So you can download an earlier version of Java and set its security to Medium.

Source: [Java Error: "Your security settings have blocked a local application from running"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196425/java-error-your-security-settings-have-blocked-a-local-application-from-runnin)

3) I also read here that only applets with full permission are blocked so if you change the permission of your applet to sanbox in your applet jnlp file you may be able to run it.

Source: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml

Comment: *"I also read here that only applets with full permission are blocked.."*  Either that information is wrong, or you misunderstood it.

Comment: On that java link that I included, it says under **Medium** Security that *"Only unsigned applications that request all permissions are blocked. All other applications are allowed to run with security prompts."* The Medium option is of course no longer available in the new version of Java.