# Embedding Java applets into html, loading from local file system

Tags: java, html, applet

I am trying to embed a java applet into an `html` presentation. I am following the directions [here](http://kinemage.biochem.duke.edu/software/kingInBrowser/KiNGinBrowser_object.html). It is the same exact app I want to embed, just with a different file to be loaded locally. I noticed that when I try to open the same page locally, i.e. when I download the demo page and run it locally, the applets don't show up. I have the following code:

```
<object classid="java:king/Kinglet.class"
                type="application/x-java-applet"
                archive="king.jar" 
                width="500" height="500">
            <param name="mode" value="flat">
            <param name="kinSource" value="kin/1xd3Knot.kin">
</object>
```

where the only difference from the demo is that I changed the value of the `kinSource` parameter. It doesn't work with the original file either.

Is there a way for me to get this to work locally?

Comment: Have you tried lowering the security settings? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196425/java-error-your-security-settings-have-blocked-a-local-application-from-runnin

Comment: I did, no change. It usually gives an error message when there is a security issue. In this case the applet just doesn't show up.

Comment: Does the Java console show any errors?  You can enable it in the Java control panel, "Advanced" tab.

Comment: Nope, nothing in console. I tried using xampp and it worked that way. Although in a buggy way, which I suspect has to do with the applet itself.