# How do I embed a java program into my website?

Tags: java, html, css, web

First off, this is for my web design class. I am doing a sort of "promotion website" for the game I made in my Computer Science 2 final for the final in this class. Everything is all good, except that I wanted to add a feature where you could play the game from the browser. The website is all in a local folder, and he will be examining it on his computer, so everything will be local, no servers. How would I go about adding the game to the website?

Comment: Are you trying to use java or javascript?

Comment: @Raptor The game was programmed in java, my website is in html and css

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: Applets are deprecated in JDK 9

You will need java applets for your java code to run in browser. Here is some intro about applets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Here is a simple example:

**Your java code:**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Applet{
   public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.drawString("Welcome in Java Applet.",40,20);
   }
}
```

Compiling the code will generate a .class file. For example: `Main.class`

**Then embed the Main.class file in your browser:**

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    My game applet
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <div >
      <APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500"></APPLET>
    </div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Some basic tutorials here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/229033-introduction-to-java-applets/

**Another way: Java Web Start**

Use [Java Web Start](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_web_start_in_or) which allows applications to be launched through browsers or via the Java Network Launching Protocol.

Some valuable resources here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info

Comment: So would I need to transfer my existing code into an applet?

Comment: aren't applets blocked by some browsers?

Comment: @IsaacLightning yes right. Code modification needed to make it run as applets.

Comment: @AlexSifuentes Yes applets are blocked by browsers however by changing some settings we can allow applets to run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196425/java-error-your-security-settings-have-blocked-a-local-application-from-runnin

Comment: What exactly would I need to change? I can upload the code if you want

Comment: The amount of changes needed actually depends on your code. Go ahead and upload the code please!

Comment: Here is the code: http://www.mediafire.com/file/d7wngymv3632pa3/SamuraiGameSRC111715.zip

Comment: It's not the best, and a lot of stuff is probably badly coded

Comment: Your application uses Swing. You should use `Java Web Start` instead of applets. Updated my answer.

Comment: What would that involve?

Comment: Ok I tried extending my main class, SamuraiBoardGame, off of Applet. I also have my html like this

`<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="1000" width="800">
    <param name="code" value="samuraiboardgame.SamuraiBoardGame" />
    <param name="archive" value="SamuraiBoardGame.jar" />
    Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
 </object> `

Now it gives java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException and I don't know how to fix this

Comment: This answer is outdated, Java applets are no longer supported on major browsers.