# How do I embed java code into a public website?

Tags: java, html, css, web, applet

I'm trying to embed a Java program into my HTML/CSS. I already found this tutorial to help me with this: [How do I embed a java program into my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029236/how-do-i-embed-a-java-program-into-my-website)

However, I'm still new to programming and for this step:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    My game applet
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <div >
      <APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500"></APPLET>
    </div>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm unsure how to do this. When you use "Main.class", where is the HTML pulling from? Is your code stored somewhere? If I want to put it on a public website, how do I do this?

I know this might be a simple question but I'm still super new to all this!

Comment: Applets have been deprecated years ago. Don't use applets. As far as I know, in 2020 there's no good way to embed Java code directly into a web page.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Web Start**

Use Java Web Start which allows applications to be launched through browsers or via the Java Network Launching Protocol.